Send Whatsapp message outside FreeForm hours
I use the following Google Apps Script code to send WhatsApp messages:
function sendTrial3WhatsAppMessages() {
  var accountSid = 'AC43136d9eda4f6c428fe8bf8eXXXX'; // Replace with your Account SID
  var authToken = '301cbac10a3e1749da28e98deffXXXXX'; // Replace with your Auth Token
  var messagingServiceSid = 'MG19bfda22e0254c0812b166d7XXXXX'; // Replace with your Messaging Service SID
  var templateName = 'shipment_reminder'; // Replace with your new template name

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var today = new Date();

  for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
    var commodity = data[i][0];
    var quantity = data[i][1];
    var deadline = new Date(data[i][2]);
    var border = data[i][3];
    var phoneNumber = data[i][4];
    var optInStatus = data[i][5];

    // Skip rows where the deadline has passed or the opt-in status is not "true"
    if (today > deadline || optInStatus.toString().toLowerCase() !== 'true') {
      continue;
    }

    // Calculate the number of days left until the deadline
    var daysLeft = Math.ceil((deadline.getTime() - today.getTime()) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));

    var url = 'https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/' + accountSid + '/Messages.json';
    var payload = {
      'To': 'whatsapp:' + phoneNumber, // Ensure correct format
      'MessagingServiceSid': messagingServiceSid,
      'Body': `Hi there! This is to remind you of the following upcoming order required by ${deadline.toDateString()} :\n` +
              `Commodity: ${commodity}\n` +
              `Quantity: ${quantity}\n` +
              `Border: ${border}\n` +
              `Please complete purchase within ${daysLeft} days.`
    };

    var options = {
      'method': 'post',
      'payload': payload,
      'headers': {
        'Authorization': 'Basic ' + Utilities.base64Encode(accountSid + ':' + authToken)
      }
    };

    try {
      var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
      Logger.log('Message sent successfully. Response: ' + response.getContentText());
    } catch (e) {
      Logger.log('Error sending message: ' + e.message);
      Logger.log('Full response: ' + e);
    }
  }
}

// Set up a daily trigger to run this function
function createDailyTrigger3() {
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('sendTrial3WhatsAppMessages')
    .timeBased()
    .everyDays(1)
    .atHour(12)
    .nearMinute(30)
    .create();
}


This code successfully sends the message, but only after the recipient "opts in". A use can opt-in by sending a message like "Yes" or "OK" to my whatsapp sender, and this needs to be done every 24 hours.
If I want to send a message to recipient without them having to opt in every day, I need to use an approved whatsapp template on twilio-- which I already have. I have used the template name & SID in this code, but the messages are still not sent without user opt-in. Do I need to make changes to this code?
Here is a screenshot of the approved template:


Can you confirm that the template was submitted to and approved by WhatsApp? That step is required to it to work.
Also, please note that this is not an opt-in process and users can also send a message saying "no" which has the same result

Yes Robert, I am sure that the template is approved, and I have the SID for it.. I think i am doing something wrong in my code.. and yes i understand that some text message has to be sent to the same number within 24 hours to endure freeform messaging. But if i am using an approved template, why can i not send messages outside the 24 hour window?

Can you add a screenshot of the status of the template in the question? Having a SID only means it's saved but it doesn't say anything about the approval status.

OK, I have added it to the post.

It seems you use the wrong parameters to send the message. You use the regular messaging API with the body parameter whereas you need to specific the contentSid and, if needed, contentVariables as explained here:
I'm not familiar with app scripts but I assume the code would look similar to this:
var url = 'https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/' + accountSid + '/Messages.json';
var payload = {
  'To': 'whatsapp:' + phoneNumber, // Ensure correct format
  'MessagingServiceSid': messagingServiceSid,
  'ContentSid': 'HXXXXXXXXX',
  'ContentVariables':  JSON.stringify({
       1: commodity,
       2: quantity,
       3: border
     }),
};


Thank you for your help. It seems that the issue was with ContentVariables & also the date format. It is working now.

Great, feel free to mark this answer as correct with the green checkmark
